# How to calculate which companies moved their earnings dates?

Tags: earnings, corporate-actions

Are there ways to quantify which percentage of companies make a change to their quarterly earnings dates?

For example company X was scheduled to report results on February 8 and the date is moved to February 15 instead. This would count as a move, or binary outcome of YES. Companies which report on their expected date, would be NO.

Comment: Interesting problem.  There are many sources that give you the _actual_ dates the earnings were reported (Compustat for example), the problem is going to be finding the _expected_ dates some time prior to the release (this kind of data is not saved anywhere as far as I know).